# I am not able to show 4-th level of an expadable list

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have an ExpandableListView with 4 level. When I try to expande the 4-th level at the end of the list, its children ar not shown. They seems in background beyond the list
As you can see in picture I should see 5 more items exploding the item 01-09-2020. You can find hereinafter the code related to the method getChildView of the adapter that has in charge the responsibility to show the 5 items. Any advise will be appriciated. `    @Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
// The child views in each row.
CheckBox driverChild;
CheckBox memberChild;
CheckBox bonusChild;
final Spinner malusChild;

```
    final CrewMember crewMember = (CrewMember) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_overall_drives_view_item, parent, false);
    }

    TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.contact);

    txtListChild.setText(crewMember.getContactName());

    malusChild = (Spinner) convertView.findViewById(R.id.numberOfMalus);
    driverChild = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.driver);
    memberChild = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.member);
    bonusChild = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.bonus);
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("0");
    list.add("1");
    list.add("2");
    list.add("3");
    list.add("4");
    list.add("5");
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(_context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    malusChild.setAdapter(adapter);

    driverChild.setChecked(crewMember.isDriver());
    memberChild.setChecked(crewMember.isMember());
    bonusChild.setChecked(crewMember.hasBonus());
    malusChild.setSelection(crewMember.getNumberOfMalus());
   System.out.println("CrewMembers member name ----> " + crewMember.getContactName());
    System.out.println("isLastChild :" + isLastChild);
    driverChild.setClickable(false);
    memberChild.setClickable(false);
    bonusChild.setClickable(false);
    malusChild.setEnabled(false);
    convertView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    return convertView;
}`
```

[image]
[image]